How to save the Fourier transform of an image such that I can modify it in an image editor?
I have a noisy image with a particular pattern and I want to remove the pattern. I save the FFT magnitude to a tiff image and the phases to a np.array text file.
I have this python code that computes FFT:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tifffile as tiff

# Load the image
image_path = '/home/gras/Downloads/archive(1)/demo_1.jpg'  # Update this with your image path
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Perform Fourier Transform
f_transform = np.fft.fft2(image)
f_transform_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(f_transform)
magnitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log(np.abs(f_transform_shifted))


# Save the Fourier transform magnitude spectrum as an image
output_path = './fourier_transform_magnitude_spectrum.tiff'
tiff.imwrite(output_path, magnitude_spectrum.astype(np.float32),  photometric='minisblack')

# Save the FFT data to a text file
output_file = './phases_array.npy'
np.save(output_file, np.angle(f_transform_shifted))

And this code that does Inverse FFT:
# Load the Fourier transformed image
fourier_image_path = './fourier_transform_magnitude_spectrum.png'  # Update this with your Fourier-transformed image path
fourier_image = cv2.imread(fourier_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Perform inverse Fourier Transform
f_transform_shifted = np.fft.ifftshift(fourier_image)
f_transform = np.fft.ifft2(f_transform_shifted)
reconstructed_image = np.abs(f_transform)

# Plot the reconstructed image
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.imshow(fourier_image, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)  # Specify vmin and vmax
plt.title('Reconstructed Image')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

How do I save this image using tifffile such that I can open and edit it in GIMP?

the 20 is superfluous for displaying purposes. np.log is the natural logarithm.

Use 32-bit TIFF or NetPBM PFM format to store both the magnitude and phase, not the log of the magnitude (i.e. spectrum).

Gimp is not suited for this purpose. Why not remove those frequency components in your Python program?

Well, you're saving only the magnitude of the FFT, not the FFT itself. You're discarding the FFT phase, which is half the information content.
Throwing information away is something you can't fix later. You'll need to save that as well, load it later, and recombine.
Also, after loading you also need to undo all the operations you did after the FFT but before saving, i.e. 20 * np.log.

These are some good insights. How should I approach saving the phase? Text file?

@CristianCutite: For consistency I'd use a second PNG file. You're probably not that familiar with the math behind Fourier transforms, but the problem here is that the FFT produces complex numbers. There's a phase for every magnitude.

A normal PNG image only has a very limited dynamic range of luminance.
TIFF16 would be a better choice of the more common image formats. You really need to use a dedicated viewer and editor to alter things reliably in the Fourier domain. There can be a huge difference in dynamic between DC (sum of all components) and AC components (sum of intensity x sin/cos(wt)).
You might just about get away with removing the DC component and then quantising the rest of it to a 16bit format. Edit that in a 16bit capable photo editor and then restore the DC component before doing the inverse transform. I suspect what has happened is that your DC component is so huge compared to everything else that to represent it on 0-255 the rescaling has smashed every other Fourier component down to zero.
Otherwise your options are limited. If your image is monochrome then you could encode the image as 24 bit colour by using the RGB bytes to represent 0-255 in each of R,G & B. Making G the most significant byte, R in the middle and B for the least significant gives a natural ordering of sorts. That would give you a 2^24 greyscale equivalent luminance image that sort of makes sense to the eye.
BTW You must preserve both the phase and magnitude of the image FFT (or equivalently its cos and sin complex components). If you lose the phase info then you will end up with an artificially symmetric result afterwards that is related to the images autocorrelation function.
Test this out by inverting the phaseless magnitude only FFT data that you have saved to the PNG file.

Did you notice the 20*np.log ? The dynamic range is pretty big, almost 13 orders of magnitude (255/20).

No. But my comments still apply - 256 level 8 bit quantisation will take a heck of a toll on reconstructed image quality. 16bit quantisation stands a fair chance of working well enough. I was mostly concentrating on the defects in the inverse transform (which also now includes not undoing the 20*np.log. The FFT could include zeroes so making log yield a Nan anywhere and the inverse will end up being all Nans. Adding a small constant to each component will fix that.

@MartinBrown i followed your advice and put it inside a 64-bit tiff file, it outputs perfectly, problem now is that I have not software to open and edit such a file, do you know of any?

Try it with 16 bit TIFF or even 32bit TIFF. There are certainly image editors about that will handle them without much difficulty. The venerable GIMP will do 32 bit TIFF after about v2.9. Learning curve is a bit steep but at least it is free.

@MartinBrown I am using tifffile to convert the np.array to .tiff file, and convert the values to a float32 array. It still is not opened by gimp, it appears as a white image. What do I do ?

The next best thing I can think of is to save it as a FITS file as used by the astronomical community. There are lots of viewers for that and a few half decent editors.  Try the NASA FITS image support site. Sorry I can't recommend one as I am way out of date on current versions.
